# MySQL's INSERT IGNORE INTO & foreign keys

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

Why in MySQL, `INSERT IGNORE INTO` does not change the *foreign key constraint* errors into warnings?

I'm trying to insert a number of records into a table and I expect MySQL to leave out the ones that result in error, any error, and insert the rest. Does anyone have any suggestions?

And the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` is not my answer. Because I expect the rows which defy the constraints not to be inserted at all.

Thanks

Comment: InnoDB, I guess. Otherwise, foreign key errors would not be an issue. It's a good question. Documentation does not appear to say anything about this.

Comment: Exactly, I use InnoDB. I should have been more precise, and I apologize for that. But as Álvaro pointed it out, the storage engine is implied so I believe I'm covered :)

Comment: And one more thing, my MySQL version is: **5.1.33-community**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**[NEW ANSWER]**

Thanks to @NeverEndingQueue for bringing this up. It seems MySQL has finally fixed this issue. I'm not sure which version this problem was first fixed in, but right now I tested with the following version and the problem is not there anymore:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.22                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1                |
| version                 | 5.7.22                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

To be clear:

```
mysql> INSERT IGNORE INTO child
    -> VALUES
    ->     (NULL, 1)
    ->     , (NULL, 2)
    ->     , (NULL, 3)
    ->     , (NULL, 4)
    ->     , (NULL, 5)
    ->     , (NULL, 6);
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 2  Warnings: 2
```

To better understand the meaning of this last query and why it shows the problem is fixed, please continue with the old answer below.

**[OLD ANSWER]**

My solution is a work around to the problem and the actual solution will always be fixing the problem within the MySQL itself.

The following steps solved my problem:

**a.** Consider having the following tables and data:

```
mysql>
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL
                     , PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

mysql>
CREATE TABLE child (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
                    , parent_id INT
                    , INDEX par_ind (parent_id)
                    , PRIMARY KEY (id)
                    , FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                        ON DELETE CASCADE
                        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

mysql>
INSERT INTO parent
VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL);

mysql>
SELECT * FROM parent;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  6 |
+----+
```

**b.** Now we need to delete some of the rows to demonstrate the problem:

```
mysql>
DELETE FROM parent WHERE id IN (3, 5);
```

**c. PROBLEM:** The problem arises when you try to insert the following child rows:

```
mysql>
INSERT IGNORE INTO child
VALUES
    (NULL, 1)
    , (NULL, 2)
    , (NULL, 3)
    , (NULL, 4)
    , (NULL, 5)
    , (NULL, 6);

ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint f
ails (`test`.`child`, CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERE
NCES `parent` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

mysql>
SELECT * FROM child;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Even though the `IGNORE` keyword is used, but MySQL cancels the the requested operation because the generated error is not turned into warning (as it supposed to). Now that the problem is obvious, let's see how can we execute the last insert into statement without facing any error.

**d. SOLUTION:** I'm going to wrap the insert into statement by some other constant statements which are neither dependent on the records inserted, nor on their number.

```
mysql>
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

mysql>
INSERT INTO child
VALUES
    (NULL, 1)
    , (NULL, 2)
    , (NULL, 3)
    , (NULL, 4)
    , (NULL, 5)
    , (NULL, 6);

mysql>
DELETE FROM child WHERE parent_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM parent);

mysql>
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

I know that this is not optimum but as long as MySQL has not fixed the problem, this is the best I know. Especially since all the statements can be executed in one request if you use mysqli library in PHP.

Comment: Another option is to use temporary table, delete from there and then insert. Because we can have not one column, that needs checks and have non-zero possibility to have bad data in another columns.

Comment: I have stumbled upon the same problem and it's incredible that in these years this still fails. And I find no documentation referring to this problem. Woaw. My solution will be to insert individually when errors occur (should not happen very often) because your solution scares me: disabling foreign key checks affect all concurrent connection I believe (unconfirmed). So in my multithread environment this is very dangerous.

Comment: Disabling checking foreign keys will affect only the current connection. If you are sharing connections within different threads, then you might face unexpected results. Otherwise you should be fine since disabling foreign keys will not affect the whole server.

Comment: Perhaps, with a table lock, that could be perfect.

Comment: @FandiSusanto If you are using MyISAM table lock could help. But if it's Innodb then a simple transaction suffice.

Comment: @FandiSusanto, If he/she's using MyISAM tables, there *are* no foreign keys - they aren't possible with MyISAM.

Comment: turning foreign key check off is a pretty ideal solution , and it's suggested to do so while inserting too many trusted rows to innodb tables

Comment: As of MySQL 5.7.22 I get correct behavior with INSERT IGNORE. 4 rows gets inserted, for 2 rows WARNINGS are generated. Disabling FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS inserts 6 rows ! Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 7):

I think the simplest, mysql solution to the problem is joining into the foreign key table to verify constraints:

```
INSERT INTO child (parent_id, value2, value3)
SELECT p.id, @new_value2, @new_value3
FROM parent p WHERE p.id = @parent_id
```

But it seems strange that you want to throw away records based on missing foreign keys. I, for instance, prefer having INSERT IGNORE error on foreign key checks.

Comment: Your solution is correct partially. It works if only you want to insert one record, which defies my first assumption that I want to insert arbitrary number of them. Also, expecting MySQL not to give out error for foreign key errors (when ignore is used) sounds pretty reasonable to me since you can easily omit ignore if you want to have them!!

Comment: @Mehran not true, you can insert an arbitrary number of rows with that statement

Answer (score 3):

I believe `INSERT IGNORE` is intended to ignore errors from the server layer, not the storage engine layer. So it will help for duplicate key errors (it's primary use case) and certain data conversions, but not foreign key errors, which come from the storage engine layer.

As for your specific requirement:

> I'm trying to insert a number of records into a table and I expect
>   MySQL to leave out the ones that produce error, any error, and insert
>   the rest. Does anyone have any suggestions?

For that I recommend using `mysql -f` to force it to keep running despite any errors. So for example, if you have a file like this:

```
insert into child (parent_id, ...) values (bad_parent_id, ...);
insert into child (parent_id, ...) values (good_parent_id, ...);
```

Then you can load that file like so, which will insert the good rows and ignore the error from the bad rows:

```
mysql -f < inserts.sql
```

Comment: I have no reason to accept or reject this explanation (especially since there's no reference reported for it). But even if it's the case, then I must say that it sounds more like a _analysis error_ which is leaked to implementation phase. Off the top of my head, the `IGNORE` keyword could easily set a global flag so any engine can check and behave as they like. I have not studied the MySQL's code so I'm sure there could be much better solutions to this problem.

Comment: The manual doesn't specifically mention foreign key errors when describing insert ignore, but here it is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html. I added an example of how to execute multiple insert statements and ignore any errors, including FK errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. But the fact is, I'm using PHP! Do you know how to ignore all the errors when using other clients like the one in PHP? I just hope the answer to this late question of mine won't include compiling a customized client.

Comment: I don't use PHP, but I would think you could just wrap your insert in a try/catch and swallow the errors.

Comment: Sorry but I don't buy that! I wanted to do this all in MySQL for optimization reasons. Sure I can find ways to do this in PHP, but what I asked for was a MySQL solution. Or in other words, with one SQL request. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be fixed in MySQL 5.7, see https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=78853.

Now foreign key constraint error is turned into warning instead:

> This issue exists in 5.1,5.5,5.6 builds but I see some improvements done in 5.7 where error has been converted to warning instead of error after WL#6614.

Comment: Confirmed, when used 5.7.22

Answer (score -1):

If you are inserting a row into the database, you can run this check explicitly using an additional query. Say you have these tables:

```
User                               Pet
userId | userName | petId          petId | petName
-------+----------+------          ------+----------
 1     | Harold   | 8               1    | Fido
 2     | Fred     | 3               3    | Spot
                                    8    | Mittens
```

and you want to insert a new user (George, who has pet #1). You could do something like

```
$newUserName = "George"
$petId = "1"
mysql_query("begin")
$result = mysql_query("SELECT petId FROM Pet WHERE petId = $petId LIMIT 1")
if ($result && 1 == mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO User (userName, petId) VALUES ('$newUserName', $petId)")
}
mysql_query("commit")
```

Please excuse the overly simplified code and bad practices in my example -- it's just meant as illustrative of a possible work-around.

Comment: Thank you so much George, but I was looking for pure MySQL solution. Something like when you try to insert a duplicate to a unique key, using `IGNORE` option. As it is mentioned in comments, no programming solution should be used. Otherwise it's pretty simple.

Answer (score -2):

Have in mind that INSERT IGNORE is not part of the ANSI standard, and there is a reason for it. You should try to avoid inserting duplicates records in the first place. Primary/Unique is not the same as a Foreign key. And have in mind that IGNORE will also ignore other error and warnings (division by zero, data truncations), which usually is not a good thing.

In this case, and almost every time, it makes more sense to use REPLACE instead of INSERT IGNORE. Another option is ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. This is Mysql's answer to the MERGE Ansi SQL.

Another alternative is to use temporary tables.

```
create temporary table tmpTable (col1, col2, ...);
insert into tmpTable ...; -- same insert you already had
alter table tmpTable add key (foreignColumnName); -- only if # of rows is big
insert into table select null /* AI id */, col1, col2 ...
  from tmpTable join parentTable on foreignColumnName = parent.id;
```

Regards,
Jose.

Comment: It's true that it ignores other warnings but if data is validated in one's application rather than relying on the database, as most who care about sanitisation do, there are no such warnings to begin with. `REPLACE` still fails when no parent row exists, and isn't always useful for one-to-many relations. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` burns through auto-increment values, and is irrelevant where related child records do not have a primary/unique key. `IGNORE` is very useful for receiving related data for records you don't have, and avoids checking via `SELECT` which can create a race condition.